# Interpolate the missing quarter with R

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation

I have a time series with quarters from 2005 to 2011. I have some missing quarters. So I'd like to interpolate the progressive series.
My series:

```
time<-c(14881.3,
14989.6,
15021.1,
15190.3,
15275,
15336.7,
15431.3,
15433.7,
15538.4,
15606.6,
15779.9,
15916.2,
15831.7,
16010.4,
16205.6,
16340.02,
16447.40142,
16581.81725,
16675.90362,
16799.3577,
NA,
NA,
NA,
17128.74,
NA,
NA,
NA,
17586.85)

library(tempdisagg)
time.A <- ts(time, frequency = 4, start = 2005)
time.A 
         Qtr1     Qtr2     Qtr3     Qtr4
2005 14881.30 14989.60 15021.10 15190.30
2006 15275.00 15336.70 15431.30 15433.70
2007 15538.40 15606.60 15779.90 15916.20
2008 15831.70 16010.40 16205.60 16340.02
2009 16447.40 16581.82 16675.90 16799.36
2010       NA       NA       NA 17128.74
2011       NA       NA       NA 17586.85
```

I tried with td function:

```
mdl <- td(time.A ~ 0,conversion="last",method="denton-cholette")
```

But I get error because of NAs. Is there a function like `na.rm=T`?
Anyway I could use the annual version of the series to solve the problem.

```
time.B<-window(time.A , start=c(2005,4), frequency =1)
time.B<-ts(time.B,frequency = 1, start = 2005)
mdl <- td(time.B ~ 0,conversion="last",method="denton-cholette")
predict(mdl)

         Qtr1     Qtr2     Qtr3     Qtr4
2005 15190.30 15190.30 15190.30 15190.30
2006 15251.15 15312.00 15372.85 15433.70
2007 15554.32 15674.95 15795.57 15916.20
2008 16022.15 16128.11 16234.06 16340.02
2009 16454.85 16569.69 16684.52 16799.36
2010 16881.70 16964.05 17046.39 17128.74
2011 17243.27 17357.79 17472.32 17586.85
```

So I replace my missing quarters with the predicted quarters.
But I think that I should use also the informations about the other quarters and not only the annual series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily interpolate your series by:

```
zoo::na.approx(time.A)
         Qtr1     Qtr2     Qtr3     Qtr4
2005 14881.30 14989.60 15021.10 15190.30
2006 15275.00 15336.70 15431.30 15433.70
2007 15538.40 15606.60 15779.90 15916.20
2008 15831.70 16010.40 16205.60 16340.02
2009 16447.40 16581.82 16675.90 16799.36
2010 16881.70 16964.05 17046.39 17128.74
2011 17243.27 17357.79 17472.32 17586.85
```

Comment: Thank you! Anyway I happily see that your result is identical to mine.